# How to hide and show modal boxes in angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I used the ng2 modal but it is not getting opened or hide through ts,
my template,

```
    <modal  id='saveeditsmodal'>
  <modal-header>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Editing item(s) in Recently Viewed</h4>
       </modal-header>
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <modal-content>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>You have unsaved changes.</p>
        </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you want to discard these changes?</p>
        </div>
               </modal-content>
     <modal-footer>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Stay On List</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)='closebox()'>Discard</button>
  </modal-footer>
  </modal>
```

My ts,

```
$('#saveeditsmodal').show();
```

Actually this is ng2 model ,i am not sure about the process to hide or show,can anyone suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Check their Gh pages they have examples https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-modal/tree/master/sample

Comment: But it does not have how to close or open from  ts file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular2, you should try to avoid using jQuery where you can.

If you are actually using the ng2-bootstrap modules, which offers a decent modal component, you should consider doing the following.

Create your own implementation of the modal, extending the existing `ModalModule` from ng2-bootstrap.

Only have it visible using an `*ngIf="variableName"`, so for instance you could do:

```
function show() {
  this.variableName = true
}
```

As part of the component.

Then in the component where you want to use the modal, add a `ViewChild` like so:

`@ViewChild('componentID') modalCmp: ModalComponent`

Your HTML could look like this:

`<modal #componentID></modal>`

You could completely extend and upgrade your component by adding `@Input()` and `@Output()` variables to it, to manipulate it's behavior.

In your code/component, you can refer to `modalCmp`. For instance:

```
function showMyModal() {
  this.modalCmp.show()
}
```

If you have any additional questions, feel free to ask.
Don't forget to declare and import your modal components using the module loaders in Angular2.

Comment: Hi Bjom,i want to use only ng2 model so i want to render it  only.

Comment: Well if you are using ng2 modal, there should be some documentation involved? Do you have the original link where you got the component/module?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see he is using two public functions to open and close

```
 open(...args: any[]) {
        if (this.isOpened)
            return;

        this.isOpened = true;
        this.onOpen.emit(args);
        document.body.appendChild(this.backdropElement);
        window.setTimeout(() => this.modalRoot.nativeElement.focus(), 0);
        document.body.className += " modal-open";
    }

    close(...args: any[]) {
        if (!this.isOpened)
            return;

        this.isOpened = false;
        this.onClose.emit(args);
        document.body.removeChild(this.backdropElement);
        document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/modal-open\b/, "");
    }
```

You could try to interact directly with the modal:

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

just add it as is in your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Better way of doing is:

Template Side :

```
<modal  id='saveeditsmodal' #saveEditModal>
.....
</modal>

<button (click)='saveEditModal.open()'>Show Modal</button>
<button (click)='saveEditModal.close()'>Hide Modal</button>
```

Component Side :

```
@ViewChild('saveEditModal') saveEditModal;
......
this.saveEditModal.open();
this.saveEditModal.close();
```